# Get value of rows when it s checkbox is checked in radgrid

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, row

I have a radgride with checkbox in each rows.I want when i click on button,it checks id of each rows that checked,put into the variable..
I know this code for gridview but I do not know equivalent of this code for radgrid

```
foreach (GridViewRow rw in grid1.Rows)
      {
          CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)rw.FindControl("Check");
          if (chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
          {


              id= grid1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text.ToString();


          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (RadGrid1.Items.Count > 0)
 {
   foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.Items)//loops through each grid row
    {
       CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)rw.FindControl("Check");
       if (chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
        {
          //string v= item["ColumnUniqueName"].Text;
            string v= item.Cells[3].Text; //accessing cell using its ColumnUniqueName
        } 
    }
 }
```

For more information on Radgrid rows and cell access, check http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-cells-and-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/loop-through-radgrid.aspx

```
foreach(GridItem rw in grid1.Items)
{
    CheckBox chkBx = rw.FindControl("Check") as CheckBox ;
    if (chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
    {
        string id = rw.Cells[3].Text;
    }
}
```